# Azure B2C Custom Policy with AAD ClaimsProvider ends in error AADB2C90037

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I've looked at several questions referencing this error, and at posts on Github and MS feedback, and spent an hour with a support engineer on chat, and still can't find the issue.

Starting with the [starter pack](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack) and (for speed) [setup tool](https://b2ciefsetupapp.azurewebsites.net/) I have configured a custom policy to allow Local Accounts access to an Asp.Net 5.0 Web App. It's not the first time I've done this, and it works well. Local users can log in with email and password. I'm using a custom policy because I also need local users to be able to change (not reset) their passwords.

I also have federated login configured from an Azure AD directory. This is also something I've done before, but for some reason this time the usual configuration isn't working. When I test Azure AD login, login seems to complete successfully, but I get an opaque error:

> AADB2C90037: An error occurred while processing the request. Please contact administrator of the site you are trying to access.
> Correlation ID: {etc}

My ClaimsProvider looks like this:

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <Domain>REDACTED</Domain>
  <DisplayName>Sign in with your REDACTED account</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="AADREDACTED-OpenIdConnect">
      <DisplayName>REDACTED Email Holder</DisplayName>
      <Description>Sign in with your REDACTED email</Description>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect"/>
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="METAREDACTED">https://login.microsoftonline.com/REDACTED/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
        <Item Key="client_id">REDACTED</Item>
        <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
        <Item Key="scope">openid</Item>
        <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
        <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
        <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_REDACTEDAppSecret"/>
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" PartnerClaimType="tid"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" PartnerClaimType="iss" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId"/>
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin"/>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

And my User Journey, like this:

```
<UserJourney Id="SignInWithREDACTED">
  <OrchestrationSteps>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="AzureADREDACTEDExchange" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>objectId</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AzureADREDACTEDExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AADREDACTED-OpenIdConnect" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when in the token. -->
    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
  </OrchestrationSteps>
  <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
</UserJourney>
```

And my RelyingParty looks like this:

```
<RelyingParty>
<DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignInWithREDACTED" />
<Endpoints>
  <!--points to refresh token journey when app makes refresh token request-->
  <Endpoint Id="Token" UserJourneyReferenceId="RedeemRefreshToken" />
</Endpoints>
<TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
  <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

And TenantId is updated everywhere.

What am I missing?

**Update**

The underlying error (as traced in Application Insights) is:

> A claim could not be found for lookup claim with id "objectId"
> defined in technical profile with id "AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId"
> policy "B2C_1A_signup_signin" of tenant "REDACTED.onmicrosoft.com

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the SocialAndLocalAccountsWithMFA starter pack, you see:

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
```

You only use ReadWithObjectid if you log in locally.

For federation, you use UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId.